# Slider,js Cann't looped out exactly with nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I added swiper.js slider EffectCoverflow effect in next.js. with auto play and add breakpoint. it cannt looped out properly.

Here is my code. and Ill attached Screenshots below.
Also ill push the code. you can also see it live here is [link https://casa-vista-real-estate.vercel.app/](https://casa-vista-real-estate.vercel.app/)

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { TeamApi } from "../apis/TeamApi";
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/effect-coverflow";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import {
  Autoplay,
  EffectCoverflow,
  Navigation,
  Pagination,
} from "swiper/modules";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function TeamSlider() {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid w-100 position-relative">
      <Swiper
        effect={"coverflow"}
        grabCursor={true}
        centeredSlides={true}
        slidesPerView="auto"
        loopedSlides={3}
        loop={true}
        autoplay={{
          delay: 2500,
          disableOnInteraction: false,
        }}
        breakpoints={{
          0: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 10,
          },
          500: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 10,
          },
          640: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 10,
          },
          768: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 20,
          },
          1024: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 20,
          },
        }}
        coverflowEffect={{
          rotate: 0,
          stretch: 0,
          depth: 100,
          modifier: 2.5,
        }}
        navigation={{
          nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
          prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
          clickable: true,
        }}
        modules={[Autoplay, Navigation, EffectCoverflow, Pagination]}
        className="swiper-container teamslider"
      >
        {TeamApi.map((e, key) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={key}>
            <div className="teamSlide position-relative">
              <Image src={e.img} alt="Team 1" className="img-fluid" />
              <div className="team_contact_con">
                <div className="contact_inner">
                  <a href="#" className="memName">
                    {e.name}
                  </a>
                  <div className="designation teamsub pb-2">
                    {e.designation}
                  </div>
                  <div className="experience teamsub pt-2">
                    Experience: {e.exp}
                  </div>
                  <div className="social_icon">
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href={`//${e.fb}`}>
                          <i className="bi bi-facebook"></i>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href={`//${e.in}`}>
                          <i className="bi bi-instagram"></i>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href={`//${e.ln}`}>
                          <i className="bi bi-linkedin"></i>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
        <div className="slider-controler">
          <div className="swiper-button-prev slider-arrow">
            <ion-icon name="arrow-back-outline"></ion-icon>
          </div>
          <div className="swiper-button-next slider-arrow">
            <ion-icon name="arrow-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Swiper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When i reload this page it shows Good.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytPui.png)

After 1 Loop it show like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTRWw.png)

and again after 1 loop it look good.

I want to work this slider proper. same images on left and same on right with proper looped.